# Reverse Number in Java using Array

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, reverse, modulus

So, I'm supposed to write a program determining **Ermips**. I've got the rest figured out, but I'm not sure how to **reverse the number correctly**. I'm supposed to use an array to reverse it.

For example, the number 357.

I use the mod operator to take the last digit and put it in the first index of the array.

`357%10 = 7`

`myArray[0] = 7`

`357/10 = 35` for a remainder

Use the remainder 35 to start over.

`35%10 = 3`

`myArray[1] = 3`

`35/10 = 3 for a remainder`

etc. ...

I need to basically loop this so I can do any length number to reverse it.

Then, after I have that array, display the array to produce the number in reverse....753.

```
public class Reverse {
        public static void main(String[]args) {
        int n = 357;
        int MAX_NUMBERS = 20;
        int currentNumber = 0;
        int reverseNumber = 0;
        int remain = 0;
        int sum = 0;

                  int [] holdDigits = new int [MAX_NUMBERS];


        int exp = holdDigits.length;
        System.out.println("exp: " + exp);
        int index = 0;

                  //sum array
       int count = holdDigits.length;
       while (count > 0){
        holdDigits[index] = n%10;
        System.out.println(index + "index: " + holdDigits[index]);
        n = n/10;
        System.out.println("remainder: " + n);

        count--;

        index++;
        }

        while (index < holdDigits.length){
        reverseNumber += holdDigits[index]*Math.pow(10,count-exp);
        index--;
        System.out.println("sum so far: " + sum);
        }

    System.out.println("Number reversed: " + reverseNumber);
         }//end of main
    }//end of class
```

---

Totally figured it out now, thanks to **Yogendra Singh** !
Check it out:

```
    public class Reverse2 {

    public static void main(String[]args) {


    int n = 76495;
    int MAX_NUMBERS = 20;
    int reverseNumber = 0;
    int index = 0;  

    //declare an array to hold the digits while reversing
    int [] holdDigits = new int [MAX_NUMBERS];

    //the exponent is the number of spaced used in the array
    int exp = holdDigits.length;  

    //while the number is greater than 0, use mod to put the right-most
    //digit in index 0, divide the remaining number and increase the index
    //to put it in the next open slot of the array.
    while (n > 0){
        holdDigits[index] = n%10;
        n = n/10;
        index++;
    }

    //decrease the index by one so it doesn't add the remaining zero as
    //a placeholder in the number
    index--;

    //count is the index because below, you subtract it, making the display
    //of the array reversed.
    int count= index;

    //while the index is greater than zero, by starting at the last filled 
    //slot of the array, the reverse number is added onto each time by 
    //multiplying the number times 10 to the power of whichever place it
    //is which happens to be the index. 
    //EXAMPLE: to turn 7 into 700, multiply by 7x10^3
    while (index >= 0 ){
        reverseNumber += holdDigits[count-index]*Math.pow(10,index);

        //lower the index to do the next number of the array
        index--;
    }

    System.out.println("Reversed number: " + reverseNumber);


    }//end of main


}//end of class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in the code as below:

1. Run the first loop until remainder of division is 0
2. Count the digits found in the division process
3. Reduce the index by 1 after first loop as it is post incremented by one in the while loop

Sample corrected code could be as below:

```
    int exp = holdDigits.length;
    System.out.println("exp: " + exp);
    int index = 0;
    while (n > 0){
        holdDigits[index] = n%10;
        System.out.println(index + "index: " + holdDigits[index]);
        n = n/10;
        System.out.println("remainder: " + n);
        index++;
    }
    index--;
    int count= index;
    while (index >=0 ){
        reverseNumber += holdDigits[count-index]*Math.pow(10,index);
        index--;
        System.out.println("sum so far: " + sum);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i apology if already you have got an answer but this is an short way to get reverse number using array with for loop.

```
    var val = prompt("enter number");
    var New = val.split("");
    var arr1 = [];
    console.log(New);
    for (i = New.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        arr1 += New[i]  + ',';
    } console.log(arr1);
```